# How do I register a .NET COM DLL with Regsvr32?

Tags: c#, com, vb6, regsvr32, dllregistration

I have a VB6 application that uses a COM DLL. The DLL is written in C#. In the C# project properties I have checked the "`Register for COM interop`" option. The VB6 app works fine on my development machine. The C# code follows this format exactly: [CodeProject C# COM Example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/csCom.aspx)

When deploying to other machines, `Regsvr32.exe` gives me the following error when I try to register the DLL:

> The module "MyCOM.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found.

What does this mean?
No tutorials/documentation I've read about COM DLLs say anything about "*entry-point DLLRegisterServer*".

We have had MAJOR problems using `RegAsm.exe` on different machines, so we really need a solution where we can run `regsvr32.exe` instead that will work for any machine that we deploy to (i.e. XP, Vista, Windows 7, x86 machines, x64 machines, etc.)

What do I need to add to my C# code to make it register-able with `regsvr32.exe`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't.  Managed [ComVisible] class libraries need to be registered with Regasm.exe.

You can do it from the IDE with Project + Properties, Build tab, Register for COM interop checkbox.  If you run Regasm.exe you usually want the /codebase command line option so you don't have to put the assembly in the GAC.  Yet another option is to let Regasm.exe generate a .reg file with the /regfile option.  You'd just run that on the target machine to get the registry updated.

Edit: just saw the "major problems" remark.  Note sure what they are, short from /codebase.  You do have to pick the right version on 64-bit machines.  There are two.  And you need an elevated command prompt so that UAC don't put a stop to it.

Comment: @Hans - 2 questions: What are the 2 versions for 64-bit machines? Is there a way to create, deploy and use the COM DLL in VB6 without registering it?

Comment: The 32-bit and the 64-bit version.  Technically yes with a registry-free COM manifest in the client app.  It needs `<clrClass>`.

Comment: @Mike Webb: As you are doing COM interop with VB6 you need to 1. compile the C# project with an x86 target and 2. use regasm under c:\windows\syswow64.

Comment: No, regasm is in the framework directory.  Framework64 for the 64-bit version but no need to worry about that for a vb6 client.

Comment: @Hans - So I don't need to use the 64bit version of Regasm for a VB6 client? The COM DLL will only be targeting x86 as well.

Comment: Right, there is no 64-bit vb6 version that could use it.  You don't have to target x86 btw.  The bitness is locked in by the version of Regasm.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple Windows application and use the code below to register COM DLL.  Make sure to add the manifest file to run as Administrator:

```
...

namespace comregister
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string framework = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot") + @"\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\";

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                button2.Enabled = true;
                button3.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(textBox1.Text);
            string fn = fi.FullName.Substring(0, fi.FullName.Length - 4);
            string dll = "\"" + fi.FullName + "\"";
            string tlb = "\"" + fn + ".tlb\"";

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = framework + "regasm.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = dll + " /tlb:" + tlb + " /codebase";
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            label2.Text = "registered";
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(textBox1.Text);
            string dll = "\"" + fi.FullName + "\"";

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = framework + "regasm.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = dll + " /unregister";
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            label2.Text = "unregistered";
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if a user has a different version of .NET Framework? In my case I seem to have multiple versions and many does not have RegAsm at all. Only v2.0.50727 and v4.0.30319 does.

Comment: @ShameelMohamed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48393660/how-to-find-regasm-location-on-a-machine might help

Answer (score 0):

Open the `*.csproj` file of the project and add `<EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>` line into `<PropertyGroup>` block. Basically it should look like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...
<Project>
```

This will generate some additional files on build. Usually you have `<PROJECT_NAME>.dll` file. One of the additional file is `<PROJECT_NAME>.comhost.dll`. This is the file you need to register:

```bash
regsvr32 D:\....\<PROJECT_NAME>\bin\Debug\net8.0\<PROJECT_NAME>.comhost.dll
```

[Official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com)

[Example](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/009a200376efa3eca8381db0041251143e5e421c/core/extensions/COMServerDemo/COMServer/COMServer.csproj#L22)