# Registering a COM object created with VS C# 2010

Tags: c#, dll, com, regsvr32, regasm

I created a COM object with C# yesterday which resulted in three files in the bin/release directory of my VS 2010 project (comclass.dll, comclass.pdb and comclass.tlb). Now, when I build the solution in the project, VS registers the class for me automatically on the development PC and I have no problem accessing the COM object and its methods from, let's say, Powershell. However, when I copy the three files onto a different machine and try to register the dll with regsvr32, it tells me that

> the module "comclass.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.
>
> Make sure that "comclass.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

Using `regasm` with the `/tlb` parameter on the .tlb file gives me a similar message. So I am a little bit stumped. Anyone knows how I should proceed from here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I register a .NET COM DLL with Regsvr32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198583/how-do-i-register-a-net-com-dll-with-regsvr32)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just copy the **dll** (and optionally the **pdb** if you want file paths and line numbers in your stack traces). This is how you register it, and the **tlb** is created:

```
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm.exe" comclass.dll /tlb /nologo /codebase
```

Since Visual Studio successfully registers it, that might just work. If not, you could also open the Output panel while doing a Rebuild and see how Visual Studio calls `regasm`.

Comment: Thanks Joe. C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>regasm c:\comtest\comclass.dll /tlb /nologo /codebase
Types registered successfully
Assembly exported to 'c:\comtest\comclass.tlb', and the type
 library was registered successfully.

Exactly what I wanted. Going to put this in my blog. Thanks again.