# regsvr32 file was loaded but the entry-point dllregisterserver

Tags: c#, dll, regsvr32, entry-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I register a COM DLL written in C# with Regsvr32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198583/how-do-i-register-a-com-dll-written-in-c-sharp-with-regsvr32)

I have written a DLL in C# (.Net 4 using VS2010). I have ticked the boxes to make it COM visible  and register for COM interop. I then saved the DLL and associated files to the c:\Program Files\MyCode directory.

When I run regsvr32 for the DLL (I want to use it in an Excel VBA project), I get the above error message. I am running Windows XP with SP3. I have searched on the other threads with the same problem but have not found anything useful.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

John.

Comment: Please do a bit of research before asking such a common question.  The "Related" section at the right of the page has lots of duplicates.

Comment: That didn't help me - I had seen it before.

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you want is regasm, not regsvr32:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.71).aspx

If you're building a 32-bit assembly, be sure to run this regasm:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
```

If you're building a 64-bit assembly, run this regasm:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
```

Comment: I have also tried regasm but that gives the following error msg - RegAsm error: RA0000: Failed to load <assembly> because it is not a valid .Net assembly. Is this just a setting within Visual Studio when I build the dll?

Comment: What version of regasm are you running? Are you building 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: I am using c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm and am building for 32bit (x86).

Comment: You can't use the .NET 2.0 regasm to register a .NET 4.0 assembly. Updated answer.

Comment: Pete - that has worked. Many thanks for your input. However, this has now thrown up another problem - when I go into Excel VBA to include the reference to my project, it tells me that it "can't add a reference to the specified file". Any thoughts?

Comment: To be used by VBA, it needs to be an ActiveX control. You might try reading this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24089/Create-ActiveX-in-NET-Step-by-Step