# C# dll to use in classic ASP

Tags: c#, asp-classic

I have the following C# code

```
namespace testDll
{
    class testDLL
    {
        public int add(int val)
        {
            return val + 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Created dll using Visual Studio Express 2010 i.e going to projet properties, changing the output type to classlibrary and Make assembly COM visible.
Everytime I try to register the dll using regsvr32.exe

I get error `dllregisterserver entrypoint was not found`

Comment: Post all relevant code in question.  Of course your C# code is missing some require elements to make it even possible to make it a COM library.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198583/how-do-i-register-a-com-dll-written-in-c-sharp-with-regsvr32

Comment: thats the complete class.I though visual studio will automatically convert to dll by selecting "class library". Please point me to the right direction, what am i missing

Comment: @delwasafewrew - a class library project does compile to a "dll", but it's not a regular COM dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot Register a .net dll with regsvr32.exe. you have to use regasm.exe. look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for a description

generally you just use

```
regasm.exe NameOfDotNetDLL.dll /codebase
```

furthermore you have to add the ComVisible attribute to your class and every method you want to have comvisible like so

```
[ComVisibleAttribute( true )]
```