# Classic ASP using C# .net DLL Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: c#, dll, asp-classic, com, createobject

Hey all this is my first time creating a COM object for a classic asp page.

The process I followed when creating this COM DLL is this:

1) Used the Strong Name Tool (sn.exe) and placed the .snk file within the app. (sn -k myKey.snk)

2) Added:

```
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile(@"myKey.snk")]
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
```

to the AssemblyInfo.cs. I do get a **warning** on the KeyFile saying:

> Use command line option '/keyfile' or appropriate project settings
>   instead of 'AssemblyKeyFile'

3) Ran the following from the Administrator: SDK Command Prompt:

```
tlbexp c:\\temp\\dll\\classicASPWSEnDecrypt.dll /out:c:\\temp\\dll\\classicASPWSEnDecrypt.tlb

regasm /tlb:c:\\temp\\dll\\classicASPWSEnDecrypt.tlb c:\\temp\\dll\\classicASPWSEnDecrypt.dll

gacutil /i c:\\temp\\dll\\classicASPWSEnDecrypt.dll

regasm c:\\temp\\dll\\classicASPWSEnDecrypt.dll /codebase
```

All registered just fine without errors.

In my classic ASP page i have:

```
<%
 Dim classicEnDecrypt
 Set classicEnDecrypt = Server.CreateObject("classicASPWSEnDecrypt.Class1")

 response.write(classicEnDecrypt.Encrypt("testing"))
%>
```

I found that the **ProgID** (using OLEView) was Class1 as seen below:
[image]

And my C# code (just a snip) is this:

```
namespace classicASPWSEnDecrypt
{
  public class Class1
  {
      public string Encrypt(string PlainText)
      {
         [code here]
      }

      public string Decrypt(string EncryptedText)
      {
         [code here]
      }
  }
}
```

Once I run the ASP page on my local machine (IIS7/Windows 7 Enterprise) I get this error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'
>
> Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Encrypt'
>
> /contactupdateWS.asp, line 49

Not quite sure why it says I don't have Encrypt function when I know I do?!

What could I be missing?

Comment: This link will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895507/c-sharp-dll-to-use-in-classic-asp

Comment: Classes cannot expose `static` methods to COM. They have to be instance methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already provided some information in comment.

I also feel that you should not have static method for this. It seems that com does not support static method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182198.aspx

Also you are creating object of class by using Server.CreateObject method so it is quite obvious that you should have instance method for this.

```
public class Class1
  {
     public string Encrypt(string PlainText)
     {
     [code here]
     }

     public string Decrypt(string EncryptedText)
     {
     [code here]
     }
   }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I have updated my OP to show the changes I have made. I still get the same error, however.

Comment: did you un-register first old assignment ? To test I simply created class library with comvisible(true) in AssemblyInfo.cs and use regasm. However when I try to add new method I have to uninstall with regasm and re-register. If still have issue try to change assemblyname.

Comment: What you tried ? Let me know. I still prefer completely take New Class Library and test with that. It will definitely work.