# Call .Net C# DLL method from Classic ASP

Tags: c#, .net, asp-classic, com

I'm working on a classic asp project that needs to send a string to a DLL who will serialize it and send to a Zebra Thermal Printer.

I have already build my DLL and registered it using *regasm* followed by */codebase* which make IIS recognizes it.

Althougt I'm able to set my object with *Server.CreateObject("MyDLL")* without errors, I'm having trouble trying to access the C# methods in it.

The C# code for the DLL was written as below:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

//[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
//[assembly: Guid("6c87161d-1e02-40ef-8512-82f30bc1ae3e")]
namespace PrintZebra
{
    //[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    /// <summary>
    /// Classe 
    /// </summary>
    public class RawPrinterHelper

    {
        // Structure and API declarions:
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public class DOCINFOA
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDocName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pOutputFile;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDataType;
        }
        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

        // SendBytesToPrinter()
        // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
        // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
        // Returns true on success, false on failure.
        public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
        {
            Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
            IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
            DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
            bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

            di.pDocName = ".NET RAW Document";
            di.pDataType = "RAW";

            // Open the printer.
            if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                // Start a document.
                if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
                {
                    // Start a page.
                    if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                    {
                        // Write your bytes.
                        bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                        EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                    }
                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
            // about why not.
            if (bSuccess == false)
            {
                dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            return bSuccess;
        }

        public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
        {
            // Open the file.
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
            // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
            bool bSuccess = false;
            // Your unmanaged pointer.
            IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
            int nLength;

            nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
            // Read the contents of the file into the array.
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
            // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
            pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
            // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
            bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
            return bSuccess;
        }

        public static Int32 SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
        {
            IntPtr pBytes;
            Int32 dwCount;
            // How many characters are in the string?
            //dwCount = szString.Length;joao
            dwCount = (szString.Length + 1) * Marshal.SystemMaxDBCSCharSize;
            // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
            // the string to ANSI text.
            pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
            // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
            bool bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
            Int32 dwError = 0;
            if (bSuccess == false)
               {
                  dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
               }
               Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
            return dwError;
        }            

    }
}
```

In my ASP application I'm trying to access the *SendStringToPrinter* method as follows:

```
Dim objZebra    
set objZebra = Server.CreateObject("Opus127Etiquetas.RawPrinterHelper")

objZebra.SendStringToPrinter
```

But debugger says that objZebra does not support *SendStringToPrinter* property or method.

Is important to tell that all the permissions to access the DLL are granted and if I start a new VB project on Visual Studio 2015 adding my custom DLL as a reference it works like a charm.

The real question is: is it possible to do what I'm trying?

**EDIT**

After discussing with some members at the comments I realize that what I realy need to know is how to change the C# methods above from *static* to *instance*.
As I said before, if I use this DLL on a Windows Application it works fine, but on ASP it didn't.
I now know what the problem is but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You need to use COM interop, and instance methods.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I've been reading lots of articles about COM interop but didn't find a real solution for this case in particular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classic ASP using C# .net DLL Object doesn't support this property or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329935/classic-asp-using-c-sharp-net-dll-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-metho)

Comment: The `static` method is the problem, only instance methods are supported by COM *(mentioned by Slaks in the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974360/call-asp-net-c-sharp-dll-method-from-classic-asp#comment90899168_51974360))* as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24330489/692942) that's been on [so] for over 4 years now.

Comment: So if I remove the static word from my method, like in _public static Int32 SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)_ Will my asp object be able to call it? 
In that case  I'll have to pass two strings as the method requires: _(PrinterName, stringText)_. Which is the best approach to do that from asp? That's the real thing about the question. I have read the topic @Lankymart says before, but it didn't seem to be clear to me and I'm desperate about an answer who satisfy my question. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry, struggling to understand the problem. Did you change it from static methods to instance methods and retry the ASP code? In relation to how to pass the parameters, will it not just be `objZebra.SendStringToPrinter "PrinterName", "StringValue"`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and patience @Lankymart. I'm not sure on how to change it from static methods to instance methods. I know it's a basics on OO, but I think I missed that class. Working on a VB Windows Application this DLL works fine. But now I need to use it on an ASP application an this turned into a nightmare to me. About the parameters, I think this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lots of research and nights awake, I realized what was wrong with my code.

First I want to thank @Lankymart and @SLaks for point me the way.

Let's go to the Code:

First I went to `AssemblyInfo.cs` and change the `[assembly: ComVisible(false)]`, and before every class I wanted to be visible to *COM* I add `[ComVisible(true)]` which I find in this MSDN document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182198.aspx

After that cames the most difficult part to me: Turn the static method into a instance method.

But, researching further and trying without give away, I changed my code from:

```
public static Int32 SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)   
{
     ...
}

public class PrintHandler
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public Int32 SendStringToPrinter(string text, string printerName)
    {            
        return RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(printerName, text);
    }
}
```

To:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public Int32 SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
{
     ...
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public class PrintHandler
{
    RawPrinterHelper rph = new RawPrinterHelper();
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public Int32 SendStringToPrinter(string text, string printerName)
    {            
        return rph.SendStringToPrinter(printerName, text);
    }
}
```

After that all went well and I was able to call the method as follows:

```
set objZebra = Server.CreateObject("PrintZebra.RawPrinterHelper")   
objZebra.SendStringToPrinter strPrinterName, strText
```

That's it. Hope this could help any other with a nearly or same problem as mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this. Helped me a lot