# Is there a way to reroute MSXML 4.0 methods to MSXML 6.0 methods?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dll, asp-classic

Our software uses an old dll which is written in asp-classic-era VB so I'm not sure how I might edit and recompile it (though I have the source code). For security reasons we have to remove the MSXML 4.0 dlls from our server, but this causes a "fatal validation error" from the old dll (I believe because some methods it calls have 4.0 specific names like SAXXMLReader40 and XMLSchemaCache40). I wrote the following vb.net dll in an attempt to reroute any calls to these methods:

```
Namespace MSXML2
    Public Class SAXXMLReader40
        Inherits SAXXMLReader60Class
    End Class
    Public Class XMLSchemaCache40
        Inherits XMLSchemaCache60Class
    End Class
End Namespace
```

This didn't work and the error continues. The page calling the dll is also in asp classic but our IIS server can run .net code as well. Am I doing something wrong? Is there another workaround that doesn't involve rerouting methods? Or is my error caused by something completely different?

Comment: Whatever the dll is written in it won't be Classic ASP.  Classic ASP code isn't compiled, it's executed at runtime.  I'm guessing that it's a 3rd party COM component which is being used in Classic ASP, and it's likely to have been written in VB6

Comment: You're right, it's not in "classic asp," it's just in classic asp-era VB. I've edited to clarify.

Comment: There are a few questions here about how to make a .net dll accessible to Classic ASP.  It's not something I've tried but maybe they'll offer clues.  Here's an example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974360/call-net-c-sharp-dll-method-from-classic-asp