# How to find regasm location on a machine

Tags: c#, regasm

I am creating an installer that registers .NET assemblies to COM using regasm. Different clients will have different Microsoft.Net versions installed on their machines. I need to know the regasm location in advance to use it.

Should I look for it only in the following locations or is there any other possible location too?

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.xxx\
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.xxxx\

Could it  instead be present in the following location?

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET**Framework64**\vx.x.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's in both folders.

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe`

Comment: If it is not found in any of the above what would that mean?