# How to register COM object and its associated Interop assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, com, vb6

I have developed a .NET application in my dev machine which is dependent on a COM object. I somehow have this COM object registered in my registry. So, I added reference to this COM object and VS.NET generated Interop for me. Everything is okay in my Dev machine. 
But, I'm trying to deploy this on a testing machine which doesn't have the COM registered. So, I ran RegSvr32 from Syswow64 folder and registered the COM successfully and Now trying to run regasm to register the Interop generated by the VS.NET, but throws error as unable to find the file.

regasm "D:\App\Bin\Interop.IManage.dll"

Comment: you don't need to register Interop

Comment: thanks, I got confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I register a COM DLL written in C# with Regsvr32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198583/how-do-i-register-a-com-dll-written-in-c-sharp-with-regsvr32)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got it. I don't need to register the Interop.
Regasm is for registering the .NET assembly (not interop) as a COM object for applications like VB6 to use them.

Comment: If you use Isolated COM, you don't even have to register the COM object.